# Data Conversion error in SQL, unsure what field it could be referring to

Tags: select, null, ssms, case-when

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Below is the code that I am using and the schema for the fields mentioned in the code. Some context behind this, I have a set list of indcodes. I only give one below but there are 350 in total. It is quite likely when i query by indcode, area, and ownership that the data does not exist. Hence, why I have the isnull language. Finally, I need rows that contains a value of suppress = 1 to show up as N/A.

For every indcode that I query, I need a result. The result could be actual data or some text (NULL, N/A, etc).

Last is the intended result. I only gave code for one indcode but have included six to give the example some depth.

```
select
CASE
WHEN suppress = 0 then isnull (mnth1emp, 0)
ELSE 'N/A'
END as mnth1emp,
CASE 
WHEN suppress = 0 THEN isnull (mnth2emp, 0)
ELSE 'N/A'
END as mnth2emp,
CASE
WHEN suppress = 0 THEN isnull (mnth3emp, 0)
ELSE 'N/A'
END as mnth3emp
from dbo.industryimport20172f
where area='000003' and indcode='21' and ownership='00' 

suppress char (1)
mnth1emp   numeric(9,0)
mnth2emp   numeric(9,0)
mnth3emp   numeric(9,0)
area       char(6)
indcode   char (6)
ownership  char(2)

123    456    789
  1      2      3
Null   null   null
  2      3      4
  3      4      5
Null    Null   Null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first things that jump out here are:

a) While you're asking for numbers to be returned in the case statement, you're then asking for a string when you get to ELSE. Try casting all the fields as varchars and then entering them as strings:

```
CASE
WHEN cast(suppress as varchar) = '0' then isnull (cast(mnth1emp as varchar), '0')
ELSE 'N/A'
END as mnth1e
```

You may not need to cast suppress.

b) Does supress ever have anything other than a number in it? If so, you would need to put the zero as a string:

```
CASE WHEN supress = '0' --etc.
```